R markdown not knitting - data set not found
I’m attempting to knit an R markdown document but I’m having trouble with the original datafile I’m using
this is the error message I’m getting:
processing file: Analysis_Final.Rmd
                                                                                                             

Quitting from lines  at lines 23-25 [unnamed-chunk-2] (Analysis_Final.Rmd)
Error:
! object 'data_sheet_Main_' not found
Execution halted

and it’s popping up in my first code chunk after I run my packages
I understand it might have something to do with the data set being in an incorrect pathway, but I’m not entirely sure how I should fix that
data_sheet_Main_ <- here::here("data/data sheet(Main).csv")
readr::read_csv


I’ve attempted using here::here but then I’m getting this message:

Error in readr::read_csv() : argument "file" is missing, with no default

data_sheet_Main_ is a .csv with several columns e.g.



ID
Exp




1
A


2
B



would appreciate any help as this is to be used for my dissertation due very soon 

You need to tell read_csv what you want to read in and assign the result with <-. Perhaps data_sheet_Main_ <- readr::read_csv(here::here("data/data sheet(Main).csv"))
